# Как указать свой класс Ratchet\ConnectionInterface?

Tags: php, ratchet

Пытаюсь сделать чат на Ratchet. Не могу понять как указать свой класс, наследующий ConnectionInterface.

Comment: для начала стоит почитать документацию и посмотреть примеры. 99.9% вопросов сразу же отпадает

Comment: @ArchDemon читал. Не нашел.